# How to detect when UINavigationController animation has finished?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit

I hope this is a simple question. If I have a UINavigationController and I push a new view controller onto the stack with an animated transition, how can I detect when the animation has finished and the new view controller is on screen?

I have a few scenarios where I need to push a new controller that then has to do a long-running operation. I'd like to push the new view first so there's something on screen before I start blocking the main thread for a long time. If I do the push immediately followed by my long-running task the view won't show up until after both are done of course and the main thread is able to process events again.

So, what I'd like to do be able to detect in the new controller once the animation is done and the view is on screen, and then start the task.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

+1 to @DHamrick's recommendation for not blocking the main thread at all.

To answer the original question, you can detect viewController changes in two places:

1. The viewController you just pushed will receive [viewWillAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:) and [viewDidAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:) messages.  If you want to know when a specific viewController appears, implement these methods.
2. The `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` method mentioned by @Mike Z is sent to the navigationController's [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/delegate).  You will need to assign an object to be that delegate in order to receive this message.  You will then know *every* time a viewController appears.

Comment: viewDidAppear on the view controller seems to be what I want. I can't do this work on a separate thread because the code being executed is not thread safe. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Comment: Thank you , your answer help me

Answer (score 4):

Instead of blocking the main thread, you should look in to doing your long running operation inside of another thread or even better, using a GCD queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    // Do your long running code
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update your UI
    });
});
```

You can put this code in your `viewDidLoad:` so that you know your UI has already loaded. This also means you don't have to rely on the timing of the animation.

Comment: As an aside, why `dispatch_get_global_queue()` instead of `dispatch_queue_create()`? I've always used the latter, but in retrospect, there are only a few cases where I need the strictly serial queues, but I guess I could shift to the concurrent queues. Short of the obvious (e.g. use serial when you need to), is there any thought about serial vs concurrent queues?

Comment: I generally create a queue when I want to guarantee single access to a given resource. For example if I have a database connection that I want to guarantee is not accessed concurrently.

Comment: Yep, I use a queue for that exact same reason and one that I'll leave that one that way (that was my reference to "where I need the strictly serial queues"). But I guess I had just gotten in the habit of always creating my own queues, but you make me realize that that's not necessary (and probably not a good use of the system's resources). I'll start using `dispatch_get_global_queue()` more. Thanks for the insight. (BTW, this is what I love about SO.)

Comment: I tried to edit the post, but my edit was too short. Just a heads up, this should be dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);, passing NULL here causes a warning.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested or implemented this myself, but the documentation sounds like:

`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`

Described as: Sent to the receiver just after the navigation controller displays a view controller’s view and navigation item properties.

Otherwise,

`setAnimationDidStopSelector:` might be something that would work for you.

Described as: Sets the message to send to the animation delegate when animation stops.